# failure scanning NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll

Tags: .net, command-line, build, nant

Part of my `.build`:

```
<loadtasks assembly="${lib.dir}\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
```

In lib.dir I have `NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll`

If I try to use `nant` this error message appears:

```
Failure scanning "Project\lib\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" for extensions.  Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `DLL` was aslo important: `Interop.MsmMergeTypeLib.dll`

Comment: @MichaelJSwart why is it not an answer? :) I have missed this DLL

Comment: +1, if you don't have this dll in the same folder as NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll, you will get the error message.